# Rails3 - will_paginate plugin strange output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have the will_paginate plugin working in an application, but when I paginate a resource it just spits out the HTML as text, doesn't provide links to the next pages and such.

And when I manually type in the URL the plugin is working it just doesn't make `<%= will_paginate @products %>` into links such as next 1 2 3 ... last

This is the output

`<span class="disabled prev_page">&amp;laquo; Previous</span> <span class="current">1</span> <a href="/products?page=2" rel="next">2</a> <a href="/products?page=2" class="next_page" rel="next">Next &amp;raquo;</a>`

controller:
    def index

```
@products = Product.all.paginate :per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]
@product_categories = ProductCategory.find(:all)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @products }
end
```

end

view

```
<%= will_paginate @products %> 
<%= will_paginate %> #for some reasons this works too
```

Comment: This happens when the value for `@products` is null OR empty. So make sure you are referring to the correct variable.

Comment: maybe, but I'm using the same variable that I loop the products with and the loop has no problem accessing the instance variable @products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reasons is the ways rails3 escapes html and for whatever reason `will_pagiante` is getting escaped.

to fix this you first need to get the correct gem as the plugin won't work so add `gem 'agnostic-will_paginate', :require => 'will_paginate'` and that is done in the new gem file located in the app folder of a rails3 project.

After that you need to stop rails from escaping will_paginate with `raw` so something like
    `<%=raw will_paginate @products %>` which is the opposition of `<%=h will_paginate @products %>` which in rails3 is equivalent to `<%= will_paginate @products %>`

Comment: I had a similar problem to the OP here.  raw, h, html_safe all did not help.  The only thing that did help was to use a 3.0.3 version of will_paginate.

Answer (score 2):

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta2'
gem "will_paginate", '3.0.pre'
```

if you run into troubles related to haml we use that version:

```
gem 'haml', '3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

will_paginate is now at this location:  
gem 'will_paginate', :git => 'git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git', :branch => "rails3"

update your gemfile

Answer (score 0):

WILL PAGINATE MOVED TO GITHUB. This repository is no longer updated.
It's recommended that you install the gem instead of a Rails plugin:

```
gem install will_paginate
```

and Try Again

Comment: gem  'agnostic-will_paginate', :require => 'will_paginate'